# iText doesn't process correct signature fields on strange situations

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature

I have a pdf and i'm processing it with itext 5.4.4 (i have tried the same with 5.5.5 and i got the same errors), while processing the file i try to verify if all signatures cover the full document and verify it with this code:

```
    boolean resp = false;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    PdfReaderversionReader = null;
    PdfReader originalReader = null;
    String signatureName = "Signature1";
... loading orginal pdf and signature names ...
    try {
        inputStream = reader.getAcroFields().extractRevision(signatureName);
        versionReader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.warn("unable to get revision for signature FIELD ", e);
    }
    //After that i have tried to use the actual one, but it still fails...
    if (versionReader == null) {
        versionReader = originalReader;
    }
    resp = versionReader.getAcroFields().signatureCoversWholeDocument(signatureName);
```

My first trouble happens while the creating the versionReader it fails on parsing bytes.
Opening with rups the pdf lokks like have two signature fields tags with the same field name.
- The first one contains byte range /ByteRange: [0, 160, 9634, 121571]
- and the second one /ByteRange: [0, 131726, 1131728, 3904]
iText just recover the first of them and after that fails.
while i was debugging code i have found that in method

```
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields.fill()

in com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields line 241 this code

if (fields.containsKey(name))
  continue;
```

so it's clearly discarding this information, i don't know but it's possible iText has a bug? or i'm doing something wrong while reading the pdf file?
The point is Adobe Acrobat reader validate all signatures without problems...

This is the [PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwBTJ2YupEtaaWo5WmhWbm0zcUU/view?usp=sharing) with the problem.

All help is well received, thank you in advance.

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwBTJ2YupEtaX3BvdTBid3RIdEU/view?usp=sharing) there is an schema with the structure of the PDF, as you can see there is a visible part of the signature, in yellow in the schema, and after that,in the non visible part, you can see the additional Signature data, there are two V tags, with two ByteRanges that i'm supossing must be overlapped to make digests and cover conformance tips, but i'm not sure if it's under ISO standard.

Comment: *two signature fields tags with the same field name* - then the PDF is not valid  For a field name there may be multiple visualizations but they all are expected to transport the same value which is not true for your PDF. Furthermore, having multiple visualizations for a PDF signature field is currently merely questionable but will be forbidden in ISO 32000-2.

Answer (score 2):

### The PDF issue

As the OP already found out himself, his PDF contains two signature form fields with the same name:

[image: /Annots of page 1 of the OP's PDF]

Both fields have a partial name `Signature1` and no parent, so that also is the fully qualified name of both fields.

ISO 32000-1, the PDF specification, states on such fields:

> In particular, field dictionaries with the same fully qualified field name shall have the same field type (**FT**), value (**V**), and default value (**DV**).
>
> *(section 12.7.3.2 Field Names)*

In case of the OP's PDF the respective values of those fields are clearly different. Thus, the PDF form field structure is not valid.

### A possible iText issue

While in a situation like this obviously a PDF library may ignore any extra field with a name it already has found a field for, the search order of iText is unfortunate:

PDF form fields without parents are expected to be referenced from the PDF's **AcroForm** dictionary **Fields** array. Old PDF forms often had form fields only referenced from the page **Annots** array and not from the **AcroForm/Fields**. To also support such forms, iText (just like Adobe Reader) considers such fields, too.

In case of the PDF at hand, there only is one field in the **AcroForm** dictionary **Fields** array:

[image: /AcroForm of the OP's PDF]

The signature field referenced from here is the field ignored by iText. It should be the other way around, iText should prefer fields referenced from the **AcroForm** dictionary **Fields** array over those only referenced from page **Annots** arrays.

### Checking the other signature

The OP in a comment said

> if i force, by debugging, to get the second one Field, the problem is that the digest is not the correct one,

As Adobe Reader verifies that other signature (at least it does not complain about its hash, merely about missing trust in its signer), this would have meant that iText or Adobe Reader has a bug in hash verification. Thus, I wrote a small test checking the signatures directly or indirectly referenced from the **AcroForm** dictionary **Fields** array. You can find the source [here](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/signature/VerifyAcroFormSignatures.java). The result for your file:

```
* A named entry: Signature1
  FQP: Signature1
  Type: /Sig
  Value: present
  Signed range: 0 131726 1131728 3904 (covers whole file)
  Validity: true
```

So the newer signature (the only one in **AcroForm/Fields**, ignored by the iText `AcroFields`) covers the whole file and verifies ok. So your *digest mismatch* seems to have been a debugging artifact.

Comment: Thank you mkl, i've made a test in this sense and what i've found is that if i force, by debugging, to get the second one Field, the problem is that the digest is not the correct one, because the /ByteRange is the second one, not the first and second one overlapped, which is what i suspect Adobe does. That's what i've been asking for intepretetation, reading the standard in section 12.7.3.2 is clear, the problem arrives when Adobe validates it ...that's why i was thinking that merging was a more complex solution, but more aligned with Adobe implementation. What do you think about it?Thank you

Comment: If you have multiple signatures in a PDF file, the byte ranges *always* overlap. More exactly, newer signatures sign byte ranges which include the byte ranges of earlier signatures and the earlier signature values.

Comment: Sorry i mean the two fields with the same name, indeed is the same signature, the visible part and the invisible one.

Comment: I'll be looking into this.

Comment: i must stop this development for a while, but if i made some correcction i'll write here

Comment: I looked into it anyways. Fortunately the digest mismatch turned out to have been a debugging artifact.

Comment: Today i've gotten sometime to test it, and overwriting com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields and effectively the bug was just an error, now the PDF is fully verified.
Thank you Micheal

Answer (score 0):

As Micheal says, if you change AcroFields in line 268 to comment

```
    // if (this.fields.containsKey(name)) {
    // continue;
    // }
```

the PDF then is fully verified as Adobe Acrobat Reader says, the bad point is you must overwrite 
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields
or go throug low level iText code.